# yii2 listview pagination, wrong url

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, yii2, pjax

I'm creating a widget that show agenda items

Widget model:

```
<?php
namespace infoweb\agenda\widgets;

use Yii;
use yii\bootstrap\Widget;

class Agenda extends Widget
{
public $template = '_agenda';
public $pageSize = 4;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
}

/**
 * @return null|string
 */
public function run()
{
    $searchModel = new Search([
        'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
    ]);
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('agenda', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'template' => $this->template]);
}
}
```

Search model:

```
<?php

namespace infoweb\agenda\widgets;

use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

use infoweb\agenda\models\Agenda as AgendaModel;

class Search extends AgendaModel
{
public $pageSize;

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = AgendaModel::find()->joinWith('translations')->where(['active' => 1]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['language' => Yii::$app->language]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['date' => SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
        ],
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

Widget view:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
?>

<?php

Pjax::begin();

echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => $template,
    'summary' => false,
    'itemOptions' => [
        'class' => 'agenda',
    ],
]);

Pjax::end();
```

Listview view:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<div class="date">
    <div class="day"><?= date('d', $model->date) ?></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="month"><?= date('m', $model->date) ?></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h3><?= $model->name ?></h3>
    <p><?= $model->short_description ?></p>
    <div class="pull-left"><strong>Plaats</strong>: Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="pull-left hidden-xs">&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pull-left"><strong>Aanvangsuur</strong>: <?= date('H:i', strtotime($model->time)) ?> uur</div>
</div>
<div class="image hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <?= Html::img($model->getImage()->getUrl('200x'), ['class' => 'img-responsive']) ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Problem 1 (most important):
When I click on the pager, the url is `site/index?page=2&per-page=4` but it should be without `site/index`

Problem 2:
I'm using a jQuery plugin matchHeight, when I go to another page, the plugin does not work anymore.
Should I initialize it again? And how?

EDIT

`$(document).on('pjax:complete', this.initMatchHeight);`

Problem 3: if I change `&per-page=4`, it's not working.
I need a default value for items per page, but it would be nice to change it in the url too

EDIT

use `'defaultPageSize' => $this->pageSize,`, not `pagesize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out it's really easy:

```
'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
    'route' => '',
],
```